# Технический английский для IT

Tags: книги

Собственно интересуют все методы, программы, книги, сайты которыми вы пользуетесь для повышения уровня английского! Особенно интересуют готовые частотные словари - как-то однажды гуглил по-этой теме ничего интересного не нашел.

Comment: Единственно стоящее и умное, что я видел но к сожалению потерял ссылку, это была прога под linux. Она парсила man-ы, составляя лексический словарь. Была самобучаема на предмет знакомых слов- достаточно было пощелкать на неизвестных словах в паре документов и остальные она помечала как известные. Далее перед прочтением man-а она выдавала неизвестные в нем слова.

Comment: полезная программа, может быть вспомните название?

Comment: Название не помню. но вспомнил, где я ее нашел <a>xgu.ru</a><br>
А вот и она <a>http://xgu.ru/wiki/new-words</a>

Comment: К стате могу дать очень дельный совет! Идем на Youtube и смотрим ролики на английском с уроками программирования. Естественно те где чувачек который катает код рассказывает что он сейчас делает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если просто английского (не всегда технического) мне дали хороший совет -> [www.cnn.com](http://www.cnn.com), [www.bbc.com](http://www.bbc.com)

Читайте новости, так вы узнаете как правильно говорить и писать, увеличите словарный запас.

В программах используйте английские имена, комментарии, вывод. Старайтесь делать это правильно с грамматической точки зрения.

**UPD**

Я за пол-года подтянул свой низкий уровень английского (по причине неиспользования оного несколько лет) до уровня B2 только просмотром сериалов на английском + английские субтитры. Что помогло после приезда за границу общаться с людьми. После года за границей уже не так много делаю ошибок, высказывать свои мысли - вообще не проблема.

**UPD2**

Знаю парочку людей, которые знакомились в иностранных чатах и переписывались, иногда общались в живую.

Comment: Комменты, имена все это делаю, но это способствует вспоминанию уже знакомых слов и изредка лезешь в словарь - вряд ли запомнишь много слов в день используя данный метод.

Comment: спасибо насчёт bbc и cnn добавил в закладки, буду постоянно читать, может поможет :)

Comment: @culebre, так это и не для запоминания, а действительно для вспоминания. Имхо, надеяться на программы бесполезно. Для детей это действительно отличный способ, а для взрослого есть много чего посерьезнее.

@G71, если не поможет, значит что-то не так, знаю много людей, которые совершенствовали знания своих 4-5 языков благодаря новостным порталам.

Comment: Я согласен, что чтение новостных порталов, в частности и особенности те которые ты упомянул, <b>разносторонне</b>(но все же проблем с выбором, что бы почитать я думаю ни у кого нет) развивают английский, но неплохо бы иметь прогу которая бы помогала в этом процессе и автоматизировала его - к примеру  я посмотрю какое-нибудь слово в словаре, запишу его, дальше мне надо каждый день открывать файлик и повторять эти слова пока не запомню - неудобно.

Comment: Добавил в ответ **UPD**

Comment: Согласен метод хорош, еще можно добавить песни с текстами(искать их ,например, вконтакте),неплохо развивает слух.

Answer (score 2):

Что касательно конктретно IT, все приходт само собой. Когда внедряешся в изучение какого-либо языка программирования, однозначно юзаешь определенную литературу, смотриш чужой код. Функции, классы, переменные и т.д. как-то сами усваиваются в голове и базовый английский переростает в нормальный уверенный технический.

Чем больше языков изучаешь, тем полнее становится багаж словаря который однозначно будет в дальнейшем использовать в построении структуры кода.

Comment: а как ускорить этот процесс? как нормально и быстро разбираться в терминологии. Порой англоязычные авторы так витеевато напишут предложение, в статье технической, что ничерта не понять

Comment: Да зачем вам его ускорять? Все прийдет со временем.

Comment: в этом вся и проблема, моё плохое знание английского очень тормозит моё образование и в первую очередь самообразование.

Comment: Как бы старость раньше не пришла=)

Comment: вово, согласен насчёт старосте, а мне хочется ТАААК много успеть

Answer (score 0):

Просто читаю книги, статьи, незнакомые слова запоминаю. Грамматику учил по самым обычным книгам. Побольше читать, побольше практики.

Comment: Тут одна из главных проблем - это проблема правильным переводом терминов. сами наверное могли замечать как серьёзные книги, которые продаются в магазинах переведены очень некачественно и вот научиться грамотно читать оригинальные статьи, книги на англ. не так просто. Я вот постоянно пытаюсь и мне постоянно приходится это делать, результат есть, но очень медленный и слабый, хотелось бы как-то поинтенсивнее двигаться, поэтому этот вопрос мне тоже интересен.

Comment: Ну читаю, я и так, некоторые темы даже вполне свободно. Но все же хочется более эффективно двигаться в данном направлении. Может есть какие-то хорошие проги-запоминалки, котороые пробовал я - они были либо детские, либо имели вообще никому не нужный функционал.  Было больше времени и опыта я бы сам бы попробовал бы сделать сервис на основе google-translate

Comment: Относительно перевода терминов - специальные словари + интернет + знание темы, текст по которой переводите. Относительно запоминания слов, поверьте человеку, который читает на пяти языках, классические методы - самые эффективные: выписывать слова, учить, составлять из них предложения, побольше читать.

Comment: а не посоветуйте "специальные словари" (желательно онлайн), желательно качественные, буду Вам очень благодарен.

Comment: не знаю, как-то обхожусь без них. Мне хватает Лингвы, а если не хватает, пользуюсь гуглем.

Comment: гугл порой ужасно переводит :(

Comment: не переводчик, а поисковик. автоматический перевод ужасен...